# Access private apigateway from with in the account vs another account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am  new to AWS and trying to access private API Gateway invocation from within the account and outside the account.

For accessing from another account, is it enough to add resource policy in  API-GW that allows other account's vpc endpoint?

For accessing from same account, I see that I need to add resource policy and also need to associate VPC-Endpoint to private api-gateway. is this the correct assumption and if so why is it different from above one.

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your query:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-private-cross-account-vpce/